# Uploading big movies (>20MB) using PHP & Ajax

Tags: php, ajax, upload, mp4

I`m trying to upload mp4 files using Ajax & PHP. When file is around 10MB everything is ok, but if file is bigger (I tried with 34MB) uploader stuck and file is not upload.
JS:

```
    function _(el){
    return document.getElementById(el);
}
function uploadFile(){
    var file = _("file-upload").files[0];
var formdata = new FormData();
        formdata.append("file-upload", file);
        var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
        ajax.upload.addEventListener("progress", progressHandler, false);
        ajax.addEventListener("load", completeHandler, false);
        ajax.addEventListener("error", errorHandler, false);
        ajax.addEventListener("abort", abortHandler, false);
        ajax.open("POST", "/app/upload.php");
        ajax.send(formdata);
    }
}
function progressHandler(event){
var percent = (event.loaded / event.total) * 100;
_("progressBar").value = Math.round(percent);
_("status").innerHTML = Math.round(percent) + "%";
}
```

HTML:

```
<form id="upload_form" method="post" class="my-2" action="/app/upload.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input id="file-upload" type="file" accept="video/mp4" name="file-upload" />
```

php.ini

```
max_execution_time = 3000
memory_limit = 256M
post_max_size = 100M
upload_max_filesize = 100M
```

How to allow user to upload "bigger" files?

**EDIT**
I just noticed, that Chrome console shows: Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET
Also - php logs does not show any problems.
PHP is working on IIS Server

Comment: any errors in browser console or server side? might as well cache _("progressBar") and _("status") as each time you call your _() func the dom elements get looked up.. does stuck mean the browser is frozen, or if you leave it 6 months its still at 10%?

Comment: Have you tested the large file through something like postman?

Comment: @LawrenceCherone stuck means shows 43% and after a while it goes to ajax.addEventListener("error", errorHandler, false);

Comment: I just noticed, that Chrome console shows: `Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET`

Answer (score 0):

Ok,
as it is PHP working on IIS direction it seems that except php.ini we need to change settings in web.config
For posterity:

```
<system.web>
        <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="102400" />
    </system.web>
    <system.webServer>
        <security>
            <requestFiltering>          
                <!--The default size is 30000000 bytes (28.6 MB). MaxValue is 4294967295 bytes (4 GB)-->
                <!-- 100 MB in bytes -->
                <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="104857600" />
            </requestFiltering>
        </security>
</system.webServer>
</configuration>
```